# Flexbox - I align items with flexbox but they are no center

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

So I am breaking my head over this. I have set global styles and I amtrying to align a logo and a navigation list one beneath the other. When I use flexbox to align it they are not actually in center. However, when I remove the global style for padding completely it aligns fine.

What seems to be the problem.

P.S. I used sass staright away.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #033860;
}

.main-head {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: #05b2dc;
}

.main-head .container {
  width: 80%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.main-head .logo {
  fill: white;
  width: 10%;
}

.main-head .main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.main-head .main-nav .nav-list {
  padding: initial;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.main-head .main-nav .nav-list .nav-item {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">
      <div class="container">
        <svg
          class="logo"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 299.92 81.73"
        >
          <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
            <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
              <path
                d="M79,70.79a6.86,6.86,0,0,1-2.19,5.26,7.67,7.67,0,0,1-5.42,2,9.62,9.62,0,0,1-4-.81L7.28,51.7A12.07,12.07,0,0,1,2,47.42a11.86,11.86,0,0,1,0-13,10.87,10.87,0,0,1,5.33-4.2l60-25.72a11.18,11.18,0,0,1,4-.81,7.67,7.67,0,0,1,5.42,2A6.86,6.86,0,0,1,79,10.94a6.13,6.13,0,0,1-4.06,6L17.8,40.86l57.09,24A6.13,6.13,0,0,1,79,70.79Z"
              />
              <path
                d="M149.32,1.82c1.62,1.4,2.42,3.51,2.42,6.31s-.7,5.07-2.1,6.47-3.93,2.32-7.6,2.75l-4.85.49q-9.56,1-14,6.47c-3,3.66-4.45,8.24-4.45,13.75V72a9,9,0,0,1-2.91,7.2,10.78,10.78,0,0,1-7.28,2.5,10.42,10.42,0,0,1-7.2-2.5c-1.9-1.67-2.83-4.07-2.83-7.2V9.42a8.61,8.61,0,0,1,2.83-6.95,10.38,10.38,0,0,1,7-2.43,9.75,9.75,0,0,1,6.79,2.35,8.61,8.61,0,0,1,2.59,6.71v6.47a24.07,24.07,0,0,1,9.14-11A27.93,27.93,0,0,1,140.42.2L142.68,0A8.77,8.77,0,0,1,149.32,1.82Z"
              />
              <path
                d="M211.27,1.82c1.62,1.4,2.42,3.51,2.42,6.31s-.7,5.07-2.09,6.47-3.94,2.32-7.61,2.75l-4.85.49q-9.55,1-14,6.47T180.7,38.06V72a9,9,0,0,1-2.91,7.2,10.78,10.78,0,0,1-7.28,2.5,10.43,10.43,0,0,1-7.2-2.5c-1.9-1.67-2.83-4.07-2.83-7.2V9.42a8.61,8.61,0,0,1,2.83-6.95,10.4,10.4,0,0,1,7-2.43,9.73,9.73,0,0,1,6.79,2.35,8.58,8.58,0,0,1,2.6,6.71v6.47a24,24,0,0,1,9.13-11A28,28,0,0,1,202.37.2L204.63,0A8.75,8.75,0,0,1,211.27,1.82Z"
              />
              <path
                d="M298,34.39a11.86,11.86,0,0,1,0,13,12,12,0,0,1-5.33,4.28l-60,25.56a9.65,9.65,0,0,1-4,.81,7.67,7.67,0,0,1-5.42-2A6.83,6.83,0,0,1,221,70.79a6.11,6.11,0,0,1,4-6l57.11-24L225,16.92a6.11,6.11,0,0,1-4-6,6.83,6.83,0,0,1,2.19-5.26,7.67,7.67,0,0,1,5.42-2,11.26,11.26,0,0,1,4,.81l60,25.72A10.82,10.82,0,0,1,298,34.39Z"
              />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
        <nav class="main-nav">
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-button">about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-button">portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-button">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine as-is. https://jsfiddle.net/faxntjg4/

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem; when I run your code snippet, everything looks visually centered in the blue bar at the top of the page.  Are you trying to get the blue bar centered in the middle of the page?  Or are you wondering why "portfolio" isn't exactly beneath "<rr>"?

Comment: Try to change browser or disable all your browser extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious why the <rr> and portfolio aren't centre. If I remove the padding:0, it works because the thing automatically sets the padding-left to 40px.